# boundary regex for hashtag and word

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, regex-lookarounds

I currently have a boundary regex that matches worlds

```
const trigger = 'foo1 foo2'
const rx = new RegExp(`\\b${trigger}\\b`, 'i');
return rx.test(text);
```

This matches the following cases:

```
foo1 foo2          <-- exact match
bar foo1 foo2      <-- end of sentence
foo1 foo2 bar      <-- beginning of sentence
```

and not

```
barfoo1 foo2
foo1 foo2bar
barfoo1 foo2bar
```

This is exactly the behaviour I want for a standard string

However when the `trigger` becomes `#foo`, this doesn't work because `#` is not valid for a word boundary.

The regex is controlled by my server, but the trigger is controlled by the user.

This is only an issue if the string begins with a hashtag so something like `foo1 #foo2` still works. I could always strip out a hashtag at the beginning.

How do I make the regex support both words and hashtags?

Comment: I hit same for 70%, where % broke the word boundary matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using word boundaries you may instead use `(^|\s+)` for a left boundary and `($|\s+)` for a right boundary:

```
const trigger = '#foo1';
text = 'hello #foo1 blah';
const rx = new RegExp(`(^|\\s+)${trigger}($|\\s+)`, 'i');
console.log(rx.test(text));
```

The problem with the pattern `\b#foo1\b` is that `#` is already a non word character.  So `\b` will not pick up on a space preceding the hash symbol.

Comment: Can't believe I was so fixated on word boundaries I didn't think to do this.

Comment: \b helps with punctuation, so this example should be (^|\\s|[.!\?,:;\(\)\[\]])
and you don't want to capture that space so you would need to strip the result, or remove punctuation. \b is very helpful, this aspect of it not working is a let down